# Passing in data to class in ES7 without a constructor function

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to use the new ES7 syntax to pass in properties to a class without using a constructor.

I know we can pass in this with a constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(pacman) {
        this.pacman = pacman;
    }
}
...
const myInstance = new MyClass({food:'........'});
```

But how we do this with a "constructorless" syntax in ES7?

Failing code:

```
class MyClass {
    static pacman; // undefined
    pacman = this.pacman; // undefined
    this.pacman = pacman; // Syntax error: unexpected token .
    pacman = this.pacman.bind(this); // Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
}
...
const myInstance = new MyClass({food:'........'});
```

Comment: I have a request at the bottom about trolls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how we do this with a "constructorless" syntax in ES7?

There is no constructorless syntax in ES2016. If you refer to the still experimental [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields): a class field is only good for things that get initialised with the same value for every instance, it cannot depend on anything passed to the constructor. That's what you need a `constructor` for. Only there you can declare parameters and use them to refer to the constructor arguments.

Comment: PS: that's why I think class fields are mostly useless

Comment: Ok, it was a hope that this was possible - sparked the idea from https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599

Comment: @CraigO.Curtis That works because the react component has a superclass whose `constructor` takes the first argument and assigns it to the `.props` property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **ES7** only adds some additional features on top of the existing features that we already have with **ES6**. And to give parameters, you will still need to use `constructors`. Just the added benefit of using **ES7** is that now you won't have to worry about `this` which you will be using inside the **array function(methods)**.

```js
        class Human{
          constructor(name,gender){
          this.name = name;
          this.gender = gender;
        };
        namegenderPrint = () =>{
          console.log(`${this.name} has the gender which is ${this.gender}`);
        }
    };

    const printme = new Human("Giggity","Male");
    printme.namegenderPrint();
```